# No Object Variable Set when using multiple range.find and findnext()

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search for a persons' name within another Range.Find but I keep getting Run-Time Error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set.
Something happens to "rngFound" within "getPaid".

```
Sub EmailClick()

Dim lastSeasonRow As Double
lastSeasonRow = Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Range("A" & Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim lastSeasonEmailRow1 As Double
lastSeasonEmailRow1 = Worksheets("Email").Range("A" & Worksheets("Email").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim getPaid As Range
Dim ErrorEmail As String
Dim colMyCol As New Collection 'Our collection

For j = 2 To lastSeasonRow
    Set rng = Worksheets("Email").Range("A2:A" & lastSeasonEmailRow1)
    Set rngFound = rng.Find(Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Cells(j, 1).Value)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        ' If its Found
        If DoesItemExist(colMyCol, rngFound.Offset(0, 1).Value) = False Then
            'Check If Already completed swimmer's family
            Dim CountSwimmers As String
            CountSwimmers = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("Email").Range("C2:C" & lastSeasonEmailRow1), rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value)
            If CountSwimmers > 1 Then
                For s = 1 To CountSwimmers
                    If s = 1 Then
                        'If first swimmer
                        Set rng = Worksheets("Email").Range("C2:C" & lastSeasonEmailRow1)
                        Set rngFound = rng.Find(rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value)
                        Debug.Print rngFound.Offset(0, -2).Value
                        Set rngBFound = rngFound
                    Else
                        'Next swimmer in family
                        Set rngFound = rng.FindNext(rngFound)
                        Debug.Print rngFound.Offset(0, -2).Value
********************** When Debugging, above line is Highlighted.
                    End If
********************************' TODO: Grab Worksheet's Name with persons' name and get Money column**
                         Set getPaid = Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Range("A2:A" & lastSeasonRow).Find(rngFound.Offset(0, -2).Value)
                        If Not getPaid Is Nothing Then
                            'If its found
                            If getPaid.Offset(0, 14).Value <> "" Then
                                'If they do owe money
                                Debug.Print getPaid.Offset(0, 14).Value
                            Else
                            End If
                        End If
                Next s

                'write name to list, if name in array skip it, when lastSeasonRow, remove array.
                colMyCol.Add (rngFound.Offset(0, -1).Value)


                'TODO: change values below to strings that will correspond with aboves combined values
                If rngFound.Value = "Michael" Then
                    Call Send_Email_Using_VBA(rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value, rngFound.Offset(0, 1).Value, rngFound.Value, Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Cells(j, 15).Value)
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print rngFound.Value
                If Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Cells(j, 15).Value <> "" Then
                'If they do owe money
                    If rngFound.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "" Then
                    'if multiple emails (primary and cc)
                        If rngFound.Value = "Michael" Then
                            Call Send_Email_Using_VBA(rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value, rngFound.Offset(0, 1).Value, rngFound.Value, Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Cells(j, 15).Value, rngFound.Offset(0, 3).Value)
                        End If
                    Else
                        If rngFound.Value = "Michael" Then
                            Call Send_Email_Using_VBA(rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value, rngFound.Offset(0, 1).Value, rngFound.Value, Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Cells(j, 15).Value)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        ErrorEmail = ErrorEmail + Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Cells(j, 1).Value + vbNewLine
    End If
Next j

If ErrorEmail <> "" Then
    MsgBox ("No Email Found For: " & vbNewLine & ErrorEmail)
End If

End Sub
```

Thank You

EDIT: Added Images for data reference:

Email Worksheet
[image: Email WorkSheet]

---

Season 2014-2015 WorkSheet
[image: Season 2014-2015 WorkSheet]

Comment: Did you step through the code  to see what rngFound is? Is it actually finding a value.

Comment: A small sampling of the data would have helped but it seems like the second match would have been better with a wildcarded [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

Comment: edited so there are pictures now

Comment: Essentially you are trying to return to a previous Find with a Find Next but in between you have redefined the Find with another operation. I'm trying to rework something for you. Instead of all of the Find operations, using some of the worksheet functions as you've done in one place should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this proposed solution, you will need to change the *getPaid* variable to type *long* and add a variable (e.g. *gotPaid*) of type double.

```
Dim getPaid As Long, gotPaid As Double
```

Change the following section of code.

```
    Set getPaid = Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Range("A2:A" & lastSeasonRow).Find(rngFound.Offset(0, -2).Value)
    If Not getPaid Is Nothing Then
        'If its found
        If getPaid.Offset(0, 14).Value <> "" Then
            'If they do owe money
            Debug.Print getPaid.Offset(0, 14).Value
        Else
        End If
    End If
```

To this.

```
    With Worksheets("Season 2014-2015")
        gotPaid = Application.SumIfs(.Columns("O"), .Columns("A"), rngFound.Offset(0, -2).Value)
        getPaid = Application.CountIfs(.Columns("A"), rngFound.Offset(0, -2).Value)
        If CBool(getPaid) Then
            'If its found
            If CBool(gotPaid) Then
                'If they do owe money
                Debug.Print rngFound.Offset(0, -2).Value & ": " & gotPaid
            Else
            End If
        End If
    End With
```

By shuffling off the second find operation, you are not redefining the first and the `.FindNext` should keep operating until you meet the *CountSwimmers* number. Alternately you could do this by not reusing the same variables but the worksheet functions should work well here.

Due to your speciality helper functions like **DoesItemExist** this could not be tested but it does compile.

Comment: You're amazing Jeeped! I cannot thank you enough ^_^